# Integrating Django-dynamic-formsets with JQuery Mobile's Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile, django-forms

I am using Django and the django-dynamic-formset plugin to generate a JQuery Mobile (JQM) site.  I have nested forms that allow the user to click a "Add" link to another line to the form.  This works great without JQM, but when JQM is used to style the form widgets the radio button labels do not trigger the correct radio button.

I have [put up a static example of the behaviour](http://johnwoltman.com/a/1.html), based on the generated HTML.  Click the "Add" link, then try choosing a severity for the added item.  The "for" attributes of the labels appear to update correctly, so I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

The [django-dynamic-formset guide](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/wiki/Usage#Formset_options) provides me with a way to call a JavaScript function after the user clicks the "Add" button, but I do not know if there's a JQM method I should be calling that will fix the issue.  When I use JQM's enhanceWithin function it triggers a page load, which submits my form to Django, which I don't want at that point because the form won't validate yet.

**Edit**: I uploaded a much better example to the same URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enough caffeine and peanut M&M's I have figured it out.

**Reason for Failure:** The django-dynamic-formset (DDF) plugin duplicates the form you give it.  But the form is cloned as-is, which already includes all the JQuery Mobile (JQM) processing.  This causes JQM to ignore it and makes the radio buttons misbehave.

**The Solution:** The DDF plugin allows you to specify what form to clone by its `formTemplate` parameter.  JQM allows you to disable automatic mobile-enhancement of certain elements.  Create an un-enhanced version of your form, and pass that to DDF as your `formTemplate`.

**More Details**:
I put this coded into my HTML head, *before* the reference to JQM:

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;   // required for using the natural forms
    });
</script>
```

And included this style to hide my "natural" form:

```
<style>
    .natural-form { visibility: hidden; display: none; }
</style>
```

In the Django code I added a `<div class='natural-form>` and put a dummy version of my form in it (being sure to surround it another `<div>` with a unique ID for reference later).  In my initialization of DDF I give it the unique ID as the parameter to `formTemplate`.

I was told on another forum I would have to hack DDF and JQM to get this to work.  I am impressed at the design of both of these libraries - flexible enough that a newbie to JQuery can stick all the pieces in the right places and get something out of it.